# Template Tag breaking the layout of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fairly basic staff portal.  Layout is just Header, Footer, Left-Hand Navigation, and a Main content area.  The Header, Footer, and Navigation are unchanged from page to page, the only section that will be different between the pages is the Main content area.  I have a basic format that is working in HTML, but when I try to abstract it by moving the styling, header, footer, and Navigation areas to a separate file and using template tags to load them into the individual pages, the whole layout breaks.  After some trial and error, it's very clearly the Navigation section that is causing the issue, and I can not figure out why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Browser is Chrome.

**ORIGINAL HTML/CSS FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>

  <style type="text/css">

    body {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font-family: Sans-Serif;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    #header {
      background: #BCCE98;
      height: 150px;

    }

  .headerimage 
  {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
  }

    #header h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding-top: 0px;
    }

    main {
      padding-bottom: 10010px;
      margin-bottom: -10000px;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #nav {
      padding-bottom: 10010px;
      margin-bottom: -10000px;
      float: left;
      width: 230px;
      margin-left: -100%;
      background: #DAE9BC;
    }     

    #footer {
      clear: left;
      width: 100%;
      background: #ccc;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 4px 0;
    }

    #wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #content {
      margin-left: 230px; /* Same as 'nav' width */
    }

    .innertube {
      margin: 15px; /* Padding for content */
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    p {
      color: #555;
    }

    nav ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    nav ul a {
      color: darkgreen;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

  </style>

  <body>

      <header id="header">
        <div class="innertube">
          <p>HEADER...</p>
        </div>
      </header>

      <div id="wrapper">

        <main>
          <div id="content">
            <div class="innertube">
              <h1>MAIN CONTENT AREA</h1>
                <p>Content...</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>

        <nav id="nav">
          <div class="innertube">
            <h3>Section One</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            <h3>Section Two</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            <h3>Section Three</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>

      <footer id="footer">
        <div class="innertube">
          <p>Footer...</p>
        </div>
      </footer>   

  </body>
</html>
```

Original Layout
[image]

**ABSTRACTED HTML PAGE FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?!= include('Style_PageLayout'); ?>

<html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>

  <style>

  </style>

  <body>
        
    <script>
      let header = document.getElementById('tHeader');
      document.body.appendChild(header.content);
    </script>

      <div id="wrapper">

        <main>
          <div id="content">
            <div class="innertube">
              <h1>Heading</h1>
                <p>Content...</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </main>

        <script>
          let NavLinks = document.getElementById('NavLinks');
          document.body.appendChild(NavLinks.content);
        </script>

    </div>

    <script>
      let footer = document.getElementById('tFooter');
      document.body.appendChild(footer.content);
    </script> 

  </body>
</html>
```

**ABSTRACTED CSS/HTML STYLING FILE**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#header {
  background: #BCCE98;
  height: 150px;
}

.headerimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

#header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

main {
  padding-bottom: 10010px;
  margin-bottom: -10000px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav {
  padding-bottom: 10010px;
  margin-bottom: -10000px;
  float: left;
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: -100%;
  background: #DAE9BC;
}

#footer {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  margin-left: 230px;
  /* Same as 'nav' width */
}

.innertube {
  margin: 15px;
  /* Padding for content */
  margin-top: 0;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  color: darkgreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}

<template id="NavLinks"><nav id="nav"><div class="innertube"><h3>Section One</h3><ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li></ul><h3>Section Two</h3><ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li></ul><h3>Section Three</h3><ul><li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li><li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li></ul></div></nav></template><template id="tFooter"><footer id="footer"><div class="innertube"><p>Footer...</p></div></footer></template></body>
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="tHeader">
    <header id="header">
      <div class="innertube">
        <p>HEADER...</p>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>

  <div id="NavLinks">
    <nav id="nav">
      <div class="innertube">
        <h3>Section One</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Section Two</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Section Three</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="tFooter">
    <footer id="footer">
      <div class="innertube">
        <p>Footer...</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Abstracted Layout

[image]

So, my question is - Why is the template for the Navigation section breaking the Layout of the page and not being displayed?  Both the Header and Footer appear to be working correctly.  I've been able to get other test cases working using the template tag, but this issue keeps eluding me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask], then reduce your code example to just one... the broken output. Create a demo snippet using the editor. It doesn't really matter what you started with. Show us what you're working with _now_.

Comment: I've converted your final snippet to a demo as an example, replacing template tags with divs. Does it show the problem?

Comment: Note that you had a style element outside the body. That's invalid HTML. It needs to be inside the body or inside a head element.

Comment: Hi Isherwood.  thanks for the response.  I will read the guide and reduce, and thanks for the example.  The example you edited actually works even less than what I am seeing in my testing... the whole main area appears to have disappeared as well as the navigation disappearing and the screen running below the footer.  Which style element are you referring to?  I'm not seeing a style element outside of the body?

Comment: In every one of your snippets the style element is between the head and body elements. This is invalid.

Comment: Oh, you mean the entire style section?  I did not know that.  I've dabbled with HTML for years, and it always just worked putting it between Head and Body.  I tried moving the style section inside both the Head and Body sections, and neither appears to resolve the issue.  The output appears to be identical to what I was getting before moving the style section.

Comment: But the HTML is not the same. You wrapped the nav in `<div id="NavLinks"></div>`

Comment: Also what does `padding-bottom: 10010px; margin-bottom: -10000px; margin-left: -100%;` try to achieve other than move the nav outside the viewport

Comment: <div id="NavLinks"></div> is actually <template id="NavLinks"></template> in my actual code, and it's supposed to be encapsulating the <nav> and all it's nested code.  Look at Footer and Header... it's doing the same thing (and that code works).  I'm retrieving the nav component by grabbing it by its templated name (NavLinks).  So, that doesn't look like it would be causing the issue.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the invalid HTML was the cause of your issue. I didn't know exactly what it was at the time. Another protip: Floats are outdated and troublesome. I highly recommend not using them. There are better ways.